# WCF web service Critical Trace

Tags: web-services, wcf, trace

I have a WCF service I want to trace. I have set the next lines int the Web.Config file:

```
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Critical, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "C:\Logs\MyCriticalTraces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
```

As you can see I just want CRITICAL messages but the File is extremely large (40 Mb every 5 minutes). It keeps getting larger and larger in a few minutes.
If I look into the file I see many messages but none seem to be Critical.

I just want to trace the Critical errors, otherwise the file would be impossible to move or open.
Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just copied-pasted that tracing code from some forum without knowing what I was doing. Then I realized that the option switchValue was wrong. I mean, I don't need the ActivityTracing log. So the line

```
switchValue="Critical, ActivityTracing"
```

Should be:

```
switchValue="Critical"
```

So the result is this:

```
   <system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Critical"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "C:\Logs\MyCriticalTraces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
```